# Why is this downloaded excel file not doing formulas and formatting cells?

Tags: excel

Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/av9ihrk20lib439/TemplateExcel--2017-10-03--13-01.xlsm?dl=0
It's from Bed bath& Beyond.

Comment: [Is Calculation turned on?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4)

Comment: How can I check on that?

Comment: click the link that is my comment.

Comment: Hello, the file doesn't allow me to format cells either.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/av9ihrk20lib439/TemplateExcel--2017-10-03--13-01.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

@Cheng YunQi, using the link @BruceWayne suggested ([Change formula recalculation, iteration, or precision](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4%20%22)), read the section located under *Change when a worksheet or workbook recalculates* to see if the worksheet is set to calculate. If it is, check to ensure that your cells with formulas aren't formatted as **Text**.

**EDIT:**

 After looking at the file provided by @Cheng YunQi, I determined that the worksheets are **protected** with a password and the example cell is formatted as **Text**. To make any modifications to this file, the worksheets will first need to be unlocked. Then the cells can be changed to a different format style to allow them to calculate appropriately.

<s>*It looks like the cells are formatted correctly, per the shared image. Try entering the cell using <kbd>F2</kbd> and then hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to commit.*</s>

Comment: I followed the link and just found out that the file cannot format cells as well. I don't even know you can disable that function.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/av9ihrk20lib439/TemplateExcel--2017-10-03--13-01.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Is the worksheet protected? You can check for worksheet protection by going to the **Review** tab on the ribbon. Under the **Changes group**, if it says, *Protect Sheet*, then it isn't protected; if it says, *Unprotect Sheet*, then it's protected. If the sheet is protected, click **Unprotect Sheet**. If it asks for a password (it may or may not), you'll need to have or get that.

Comment: Your workbook has protected sheets, and those cells where your formulas live are formatted as Text. You won't be able to do anything with this workbook unless and until you get the passwords for those sheets.